# ExecutorService.invokeAll(timeout, TimeUnit) vs Future.get(timeout, TimeUnit)

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I am using the **ExecutorService.invokeAll(Callable, timeout, TimeUnit)** method

And inside each of the Callable submitted to ExecutorService I have a **future.get()**

Will the *future.get()* would still be running in the background even if the executorService has timed out ?

Do I have to specify the timeout on the **future.get(timeout, TimeUnit)** as well and throw a *TimeoutException* so as to make sure the future is terminated ?

Answer (score 2):

As [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) states:

> Upon return, tasks that have not completed are cancelled.

It’s not stated explicitly, but it uses `Future.cancel(true)`, i.e. interrupt the running tasks. Since `Future.get()` supports interruption, this will cause it to complete by throwing an `InterruptedException`. If your `Callable` does not catch it nor does anything that could reset the interruption state, this implies that the callables will stop waiting in `Future.get()` if the timeout specified to `invokeAll` elapsed.

However, `invokeAll` only cancels the futures, hence, sends the interruption signal but does not wait for the threads to react on it and complete the execution of the `Callable`’s code. So by the time, `invokeAll` completes due to a timeout, some of the threads might still run on already cancelled tasks. But if these tasks merely consist of a `future::get`, this should not be an issue.

---

But if all you want to do, is to wait for the completion of a list of existing `Future`s, you can do this more efficient. After all, you are wrapping each `Future` into a `Callable` invoking `Future.get`, which `invokeAll` will wrap into another `Future`, potentially blocking one worker thread per future, followed by waiting for the completion of all of these future. The last step is exactly what this task is about, so you could do it without the previous steps, e.g.

```
public static void waitForAll(Collection<? extends Future<?>> futures,
                              long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
    throws InterruptedException {

    long nanos = unit.toNanos(timeout);
    boolean done = false;
    try {
        final long deadline = System.nanoTime() + nanos;
        final int size = futures.size();
        for(Future<?> f: futures) {
            if(!f.isDone()) {
                if (nanos <= 0L) return;
                try { f.get(nanos, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS); }
                catch(CancellationException | ExecutionException ignore) {}
                catch(TimeoutException toe) { return; }
                nanos = deadline - System.nanoTime();
            }
        }
        done = true;
    }
    finally { if (!done) for(Future<?> f: futures) f.cancel(true); }
}
```

This is basically how `AbstractExecutorService` waits for the completion of all futures, after having submitted all `Callable`s, creating a `Future` for each. As said, if all you want to do is to wait for a list of existing futures, you can do this directly without wasting resources by submitting jobs to an executor. Another benefit of using this method is that this will cancel the original futures rather than just cancelling the jobs that wait for the futures. You can also rely on this method cancelling with interruption whereas this property is not specified explicitly for `invokeAll`,

Answer (score 0):

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

> Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete or the timeout expires

So 1. all results will have been provided by all `Callable`s, including the result from the `future.get()` call inside, and 2. once invokeAll returns (before the timeout, that is), all futures will have terminated.

Comment: Lets say some of the future.get() did not receive any result. And the executor service times out. What happens to all those future.get() ? Will they still exist ?

Comment: @user1142317 Then the timeout of `invokeAll` would trigger.